# I am trying to model using xgboost regressor and the error coming thorough

Tags: python, regression, spyder, xgboost

I am new to python and encountering this error while fitting xgboost regression model (using spyder)[code filee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYcrt.jpg)
[error message for console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnGkT.jpg)

Comment: Does this help https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and apply good proactices to ask question